# Mapping two arrays at same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have two different arrays that I need to map together. The indexes values from the arr1 gets used by the arr2 and the data from arr2 gets rendered with data from arr1 accordingly.
[image]

As in the image, the data in column-one belongs to arr2 and data in column-two belongs to arr1.

```
this.state={
    color:['red','green','blue', 'black'],
    data:[{
        Cars: ['ModelA', 'ModelB', 'ModelC']
    }]
}

componentDidMount(){
    const color_code = Object.assign( {}, (this.state.color));


        this.setState({
            color:color_code
        })
}


render(){
    const list = this.state.data.Cars.map( (item, index) => {
            const col = this.state.color[index];


            return (
                <View key={item.id}>
                        <View style={{width: 15,height: 15,borderRadius: 50, backgroundColor: col}} />

                        <View>
                            {item.map((name, i) => (
                                <Text style={{fontSize:12, paddingBottom:12, color:'gray'}}>{name}</Text>
                            ))}
                        </View>
                </View>
            )
    })
}
```

Here is my snippet what I was trying to do. All I get is only *'Red'* color as output in column-one while complete models list in column-two.

Please help to rectify this.

Comment: Your `data` variable has an invalid definition. That is not a valid literal. In fact, the whole assignment to `state` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @trincot I edited it. Is it okay now? Actually it is just a dummy data i am using here. The whole data is lot big enough

Comment: No, the equal signs are invalid syntax. Also, you never reference `Cars`. That should be a big hint as why it does not work.

Comment: Sorry These are the typos I am making. I am really sorry. In y actual code it's semi-colon (as it should be), but still not getting desired result.

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle and put up here, so that I can edit it and help you with the solution

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-native-4kgtf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a small refactoring of your code. For explanation see comments:

```
renderCars(){
      // make sure to really access your cars array 
      const list = this.state.data[0].Cars.map( (item, index) => {

            const color = this.state.color[index];
            // render Modelname and color side by side 
            return (
                <View key={index} style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                       <View style={{width: 15,height: 15,borderRadius: 5, backgroundColor: color }} /> 

                        <View>

                                <Text style={{fontSize:12, paddingBottom:12, color:'gray'}}>{item}</Text>

                        </View>
                </View>
            )
    });
    return list;

}

render(){

    return ( 
      <View  style={styles.container}> 
      {this.renderCars()} 
      </View>
      );
}
```

**Here is a complete working example:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/sponaneous-croissant

**Edit:** Explanation about modulo operator:

The modulo operator is a mathematical function. Here we can make sure that we only access indices inside the array which really exist.

Here are some examples:

```
1 % 3 = 1 
3 % 3 = 0 
4 % 3 = 1
```

For your example the modulo operator is not necessary, but it is a good idea to use it. Especially if you have more cars than colors and you want to reuse the colors

Comment: This Worked. But [index%this.state.color.length] How this modulo operator helps to access the colors?

Comment: @bubble-cord i've updated my answer, the modulo operator is not really necessary in this example.